# Building interactive WHERE clause for Postgresql queries from PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm using Postgresql 9.2 and PHP 5.5 on Linux. I have a database with "patient" records in it, and I'm displaying the records on a web page. That works fine, but now I need to add interactive filters so it will display only certain types of records depending on what filters the user engages, something like having 10 checkboxes from which I build an ad-hoc WHERE clause based off of that information and then rerun the query in realtime. I'm a bit unclear how to do that.

How would one approach this using PHP?

Comment: Let me give a more concrete example. Suppose I have a number of checkboxes where the user can select one or more as filter elements on the query. The checkboxes might be "red", "green", and/or "blue", so the user can filter seeing any or all of these types of records as displayed in a large text box. My question is this: How in PHP do I have those checkbox selection events invoke a re-execution of the query? This is the part that I don't know how to approach.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is recieve all the data of your user's selected filters with $_POST or $_GET and then make a small function with a loop to concatenate everything the way your query needs it.

Something like this... IN THE CASE you have only ONE field in your DB to match with. It's a simple scenario and with more fields you'll need to make it so that you add the field you really need in each case, nothing too complex.

```
<?php 

//recieve all the filters and save them in array

$keys[] = isset($_POST['filter1'])?'$_POST['filter1']':'';  //this sends empty if the filter is not set.
$keys[] = isset($_POST['filter2'])?'$_POST['filter2']':''; 
$keys[] = isset($_POST['filter3'])?'$_POST['filter3']':''; 


//Go through the array and concatenate the string you need. Of course, you might need AND instead of OR, depending on what your needs are.
foreach ($keys as $id => $value) {
    if($id > 0){
       $filters.=" OR ";
    }
    $filters.=" your_field = '".$value."' ";
}

//at this point $filters has a string with all your 

//Then make the connection and send the query. Notice how the select concatenates the $filters variable

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "user"; 
$pass = "pass"; 
$db = "database"; 

$con = pg_connect("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass")
    or die ("Could not connect to server\n"); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ".$filters; 

$rs = pg_query($con, $query) or die("Cannot execute query: $query\n");

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($rs)) {
  echo "$row[0] $row[1] $row[2]\n";

  //or whatever way you want to print it...
}

pg_close($con); 

?>
```

The above code will get variables from a form that sent 3 variables (assuming all of them correspond to the SAME field in your DB, and makes a string to use as your WHERE clause.

If you have more than one field of your db to filter through, all you need to do is be careful on how you match the user input with your fields.

NOTE: I did not add it here for practical reasons... but please, please  sanitize user input.. ALWAYS sanitize user input before using user controlled data in your queries.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do string concatenation. Once you have the values just pass them to the **constant** query string:

```
$query = "
    select a, b
    from patient
    where
        ($x is not null and x = $x)
        or
        ('$y' != '' and y = '$y')
";
```

If the value was not informed by the user pass it as null or empty. In the above query the `x = $x` condition will be ignored if `$x` is null and the `y = '$y'` condition will be ignored if `$y` is empty.

With that said, a check box will always be either true or false. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Always **sanitize** the user input or use a driver to do it for you!

Comment: In the database records there are fields for which site, which patient, which doctor, etc, made the entry. I'm trying to have a way for users to select from a programmed set of options in a table which fields and values to filter on. That way there's no need for sanitizing input.

What I don't quite know how to do is to make it so that when a user makes a filter selection (from a list, say) that this fires off the query again on the same page. What hookup / setup does PHP use for this type of event?

Comment: @Jon _That way there's no need for sanitizing input_. Yes, sure there is. _that this fires off the query_ Your doubt is about HTML and a tiny bit of javascript. Rewrite your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [Where clause builder](https://github.com/chanmix51/Pomm/blob/master/Pomm/Query/Where.php) exactly for that purpose. It comes with the Pomm project but you can use it stand alone.

```
<?php

$where = Pomm\Query\Where::create("birthdate > ?", array($date->format('Y-m-d')))
    ->andWhere('gender = ?', array('M'));

$where2 = Pomm\Query\Where::createWhereIn('something_id', array(1, 15, 43, 104))
    ->orWhere($where);

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE %s", $where2);

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bind($where2->getValues());

$results = $statement->execute();
```

This way, your values are escaped and you can build dynamically your where clause. You will find more information in [Pomm's documentation](http://pomm.coolkeums.org/documentation/manual-1.1#and-or-the-where-class).